# How do you pass user input from main to other classes?

Tags: c++, user-input

```
#include <iostream>
#include "multiplication.h"
#include "subtraction.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

    multiplication out;
    subtraction out2;

    int x, y, z;
    int product;
    int difference;

    cout << "Enter two numbers to multiply by: ";
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y; 
    product = out.mult();
    cout << "the product is: " << product;

    cout << "Now enter a number to subtract the product by: ";
    cin >> z;
    difference = out2.sub();
    cout << "the difference is: " << difference;
}

    #pragma once

class multiplication
{
public:

    int mult();

};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "multiplication.h"

int multiplication::mult(int x, int y) {

    return x * y;
}

    #pragma once
class subtraction
{
public:

    int sub();
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "subtraction.h"

int subtraction::sub(int product, int z) {

    return product - z;
}
```

I need to pass the user input variables from main to mult and the user input z and product from main to sub. I tried passing them as args in the functions I've created, but they are not accessed.

Edit: I added multiplication.h and subtraction.h
In them I just have the call to the function declarations for the class.

Comment: literally: `product = out.mult(x, y);`  and `difference = out2.sub(product, z);`

Comment: I would help if you printed the code to `multiplication.h` and `subtraction.h` to confirm the assumptoins I just made.

Comment: I added the .h files. When I pass x,y or product,z. It errors telling me there are too many args for the function call.

Comment: Exactly,  You declared `mult` as a method taking no parameters, but defined it as a method taking two.  You need a good book on C++ - this is chapter 1 stuff.

Comment: I got it working by adding the function arguments in my header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass them to the function call as arguments

```
 difference = out2.sub(x, y);
```

In the .h files you should define them with arguments

```
class subtraction
{
    public:    
    int sub(int x, int y);
};
```

[Function overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/function-overloading?view=msvc-170)

Comment: Good answer, but "function overloading" doesn't really apply.

Comment: I believe the difference between func() and func(int x, int y) is related to function overloading.

Comment: I don't think OP is trying to do function overloading. He's just confused about how to delcare a method in the class declaration and how to define it outside of it.

Comment: Yes you are probably right, but function overloading is somehow related and will be helpful for him in order to distinguish functions at least. It is bonus information for this question :)